# Unable to print wanted item from json api

Tags: python, json, api, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to print the 'temp' item from a json urlfile. The problem is, I can't just type in `print(item['temp']`
If i do I get this error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

So I figured I had to use an integer instead, which is what I did. But when it
prints out the result I got this:

"f
c"

This doesn't make any sense, doesn't matter what number I type in I get a result in the form of 2 letters.

Here's the code:

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=fRnJKj3Xpi&output=json&query=SW1")
readurl = url.read()
json_obj = str(readurl, "utf-8")
data = json.loads(json_obj)

for item in data['weather']:
    print(item[0])
```

Comment: That's because `item` is a string, not a dict. They are *keys* in a dictionary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How does one call an item in such a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data['weather']` is a *dictionary*, and looping directly over a dictionary produces the keys in that dictionary. Here each key is a string; either `'curren_weather'` or `'forecast'`. As such, `item[0]` takes the first letter of each of these keys, so you end up printing `f` and `c`:

```
>>> for item in data['weather']:
...     print(item)
...
curren_weather
forecast
>>> for item in data['weather']:
...     print(item[0])
...
c
f
```

I take it you want to print the `'temp'` key of the list of dictionaries in the list referenced by `curren_weather` instead:

```
for curr in data['weather']['curren_weather']:
    print(curr['temp'] + curr['temp_unit'])
```

I added the `temp_unit` value too; the above outputs:

```
15c
```